# How to shorten multiple If with ascending index of named ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets formula like this with two named range: RangeA and RangeB.

```
=(1+VLOOKUP($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0)) * VLOOKUP($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0)
+ if(B2>=11,(index(Test!RangeB,1,2) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(index(Test!RangeB,1,1)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0),0)
+ if(B2>=21,(index(Test!RangeB,2,2) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(index(Test!RangeB,2,1)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0),0)
+ if(B2>=41,(index(Test!RangeB,3,2) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(index(Test!RangeB,3,1)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0),0)
+ if(B2>=61,(index(Test!RangeB,4,2) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(index(Test!RangeB,4,1)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0),0)
+ if(B2>=81,(index(Test!RangeB,5,2) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(index(Test!RangeB,5,1)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0),0)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4Xc8PMXjUVuI2SXY3QgkqrYQn3xc922bYJjH0KHX2Q/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is: it contains many long if (it is much longer than the example above) which I think could be shortened since it increases the index 1 row per time. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this formula is supposed to do. Could you expand on that?

Comment: lamblichus: It's for calculating the power of a hero in my game. It was simplified though.
@ScottCraner: Google sheets, sir

Answer (score 2):

Replace the INDEX with:

```
vlookup(row(indirect("1:"&match(B2,index(Test!RangeB,0,1)))),{row(Test!RangeB)-min(row(Test!RangeB))+1,Test!RangeB},3,false)
```

Keep the first `IF` and get rid of the rest:

```
=(1+VLOOKUP($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0)) * VLOOKUP($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0)
+ if(B2>=11,sumproduct((vlookup(row(indirect("1:"&match(B2,index(Test!RangeB,0,1)))),{row(Test!RangeB)-min(row(Test!RangeB))+1,Test!RangeB},3,false) - 1) * ((1+vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,2,0))^(vlookup(row(indirect("1:"&match(B2,index(Test!RangeB,0,1)))),{row(Test!RangeB)-min(row(Test!RangeB))+1,Test!RangeB},2,false)-1)) * vlookup($A2,Test!RangeA,3,0)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it is only correct on the first row: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4Xc8PMXjUVuI2SXY3QgkqrYQn3xc922bYJjH0KHX2Q/edit#gid=403260859

Comment: It works with the fixed values of RangeB. But if I change  81 -> 80, it  will no longer work. As I mentioned, I shortened the value of those ranges.

Comment: I would put the lowest value at the transition, I cannot think of another method.  You need a lookup of the steps or you are back to your method.

Comment: or are you saying that you changed `H20` to `80` and it stopped working?

Comment: You need to change your original formula also if you change the step to 80 in the rangeB.  Then the formulas returns will match.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Will try to apply to my real sheets and let you know soon.